# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in fire bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am getting the syntax error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

From this jQuery code:

```
$("#createEnquiry").text(${noEnqMsg});
```

What kinds of mistakes produce this **Javascript** Syntax error?

Comment: what's with the curly braces? are you sure about that?

Comment: you are missing `)` can you add all the relevant code? is `${noEnqMsg}` a variable?

Comment: Is `noEnqMsg` a variable? Where is the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you meant to use string quotes:

```
$("#createEnquiry").text("${noEnqMsg}");
```

Or maybe you though you were using [*template strings*](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html):

```
$("#createEnquiry").text(`${noEnqMsg}`);
```

Comment: you think its a variable of some sort?

Comment: If he did mean to use a template string then yes. Only he knows to be truthfull

Comment: yes . you are correct .. now it is working  :) thank u basarat

Comment: @shyamli you should tick the check mark to mark this question answered

Answer (score 2):

You might need to use **template strings** as given in below code statement

```
$("#createEnquiry").text(`${noEnqMsg}`);
```

Since it is introduced in ES6 notations. I would recommend to transpile it to ES5 annotations. Also note that ES6 syntax is currently supported on latest browsers only e.g. Chrome, Firefox. Here is the reference link for more details.

[ES6 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)